# CSS two column layout aligned-left?

Tags: css, alignment

I have a simple design. To the left is the navbar, to the right is the content div. I just did float left and float right and it works - unless the monitor is too wide. Then the navbar is far off to the left (like it should) but the content clings to the right. The middle is empty space. I want the content to cling next to the navbar on the left.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Post some code, it's much easier for us to help you if you "show your work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about floating them both to the left and use percentage values to set their width..
Like below:

```
#sidebar,#content {float:left;}
#sidebar {width:25%;}
#content {width:75%}
```

Or if you want to fix the size of your sidebar and have the content fills the rest of the space you can do the following(I use it all the time):

HTML:

```
<div id="content"><div class="in">
CONTENT HERE
</div></div>

<div id="sidebar">
SIDEBAR HERE
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content,#sidebar {float:left;}
#sidebar {width:300px; position:relative;/*so content won't cover it*/}
#content {width:100%; margin-right:-300px;/*sidebar's width*/}
     #content .in {margin-right:300px;
                   /*sidebar's width or more for space between blocks*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of method to do that.

It depends :

- if you want a fixed width layout, or a relative one.
- if you want the layout to be centered or not.
- etc.

A sketch of what you want or/and your actual code would help.

Anyway, if you're not aware of CSS layout, you could use a CSS framework like [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) which is easy to use and takes care of your current problem by itself.